# Get the last record in each group with sum/count

Tags: java, mysql, group-by, sum

There is a table **table1** that contains data as shown below:
code & amount is fields of table1.

I want to generate of report from records from **table1** with group by each code and also get sum of each code, as shown below

[image]

Any idea about how to generate an output like above?
For Java development

Comment: In Java? MYSQL isn't good (or designed) for presenting data in anything other than a most rudimentary way. And do you really want heading row, data rows , sum row and blank row as literally in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're really looking for 2 sets of results here. The individual row output and the group by output require 2 separate queries.

You could

```
SELECT code, amount
FROM table1
ORDER BY code
```

for the individual amounts, and

```
SELECT code, sum(amount)
FROM table1
GROUP BY code
```

for the sums.

Personally I'd rather avoid making a second query. Just use the first query and do the summing/formatting from within my Java code.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) a map from this table and group duplicates into a `list`. Then to represent data you can iterate over this map and get the [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) of each list.

Example of output to the markdown table:

```java
String[][] table = {
        {"aaa", "10"},
        {"aaa", "5"},
        {"aaa", "20"},
        {"bbb", "30"},
        {"bbb", "5"},
        {"ccc", "40"}};
```

```java
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = Arrays.stream(table)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                arr -> arr[0],
                arr -> new ArrayList<>(List.of(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]))),
                (list1, list2) -> {
                    list1.addAll(list2);
                    return list1;
                }, TreeMap::new));
```

```java
// raw output
System.out.println(map);
// {aaa=[10, 5, 20], bbb=[30, 5], ccc=[40]}
```

```java
// output to the markdown table
map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    System.out.println("| code | amount |");
    System.out.println("|---|---|");
    value.forEach(element ->
            System.out.println("| " + key + " | " + element + " |"));
    System.out.println("| <b>Sum</b> | <b>" + value.stream()
            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum() + "</b> |");
    System.out.println();
});
```

| code | amount |
| --- | --- |
| aaa | 10 |
| aaa | 5 |
| aaa | 20 |
| **Sum** | **35** |

| code | amount |
| --- | --- |
| bbb | 30 |
| bbb | 5 |
| **Sum** | **35** |

| code | amount |
| --- | --- |
| ccc | 40 |
| **Sum** | **40** |